# Even after seasonality adjustment, seasonality still remains. Why?

Tags: time-series, arima, seasonality, decomposition

I'm trying the classic AirPassengers dataset in R and tried removing the seasonal component using `deSeas <- forecast::seasadj(decompose(d,"multiplicative"))`, but it doesn't seem to go away.
Original data:
[image]
Seasonality viewed with `plot(decompose(d,"multiplicative"))`:
[image]
Seasonality adjusted with

```
deSeas <- forecast::seasadj(decompose(d,"multiplicative"))
plot(deSeas)
```

[image]

But decompose still shows a seasonal pattern, `plot(decompose(deSeas,"multiplicative"))`:

[image]

I don't understand why there still is a seasonality. Should I de-seasonalize it again? Will arima be able to re-incorporate the single de-seasonalized or double de-seasonalized data back into the predictions that it tries to make?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`decompose` will decompose *any* time series, whether there is a seasonal signal or not. It does not do, e.g., a significance test, and quit if there is no discernible seasonal signal. It is kind of dumb that way.

Note the $y$ axes of your two decomposition plots. In the decomposition of the original data, the seasonal component goes from 0.80 to 1.20, so we have roughly a 20% seasonal signal. When you decompose the already-decomposed data, the seasonal component goes from 0.998 to 1.002, so we have a roughly 0.2% seasonal "signal". I'd say this is consistent with no remaining seasonality in the decomposed series. A number of standard seasonality tests are of the same opinion:

```
library(forecast)
nsdiffs(deSeas,test="seas")
# [1] 0
nsdiffs(deSeas,test="ch")
# [1] 0
nsdiffs(deSeas,test="hegy")
# [1] 0
nsdiffs(deSeas,test="ocsb")
# [1] 0
```

When you are faced with some hard-to-understand statistical behavior, it is often instructive to check how your method performs on completely random data. In the present case, you can see that `decompose()` will happily decompose completely unseasonal random noise. However, note again the $y$ axis on the seasonal component in the plot:

[image: decomposition random data]

```
set.seed(1)
foo <- ts(rnorm(144),frequency=12)+10
plot(decompose(foo,"multiplicative"))
```

One difference between `plot(decompose(deSeas,"multiplicative"))` and `plot(decompose(foo,"multiplicative"))` is visible: `deSeas` gives a far more regular seasonal component. As such, there may be some tiny remaining seasonality. I would assume that the true `AirPassengers` data generating process is not *completely* multiplicative, so even after multiplicative deseasonalization, some very little signal remains.

One could investigate this by generating some data with a true multiplicative DGP, then check whether `decompose()` correctly removes the seasonality, leaving something that, when decomposed again like the `foo` series, shows a seasonal component that is periodic but noisy.