# Modeling timeseries with strong seasonality

Tags: time-series, python, arima, garch, seasonality

I have [monthly national home price index data](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/CSUSHPISA#0), from CoreLogic. Data is seasonally adjusted. But still has strong seasonal effect. Here is the plot for monthly changes.

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose

# Decompose the time series to find seasonality
decompose_result = seasonal_decompose(national_returns, model='additive', period=12)

# Plot the decomposed components
fig = decompose_result.plot()
fig.set_size_inches(10, 7)
plt.show()
```

[image]

We can see seasonal effect as well as volatility clustering. My plan was to fit a SARIMA(1,0,1)x(1,0,0,12) and then a GARCH model. After I fit SARIMA, I was doing additional Ljung-Box test, and the p-values are not $> 0.05$ for higher lags.

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA

# Fit an ARIMA(1,0,0) model
model = ARIMA(national_returns, order=(1,1,0), seasonal_order=(1,0,0,12))
model_fit = model.fit()
# Display the model summary
model_summary = model_fit.summary()

# Extract the residuals
residuals = model_fit.resid

print(model_summary)

model_fit.test_serial_correlation('ljungbox',df_adjust=True,lags=20)
```

My questions are -

1. How would you model this?
2. My plan is to fit GARCH on the residuals. I am using Python. Is there a better way?

Edit : Here are the results from AR(1), ARIMA(1,1,0) and SARIMA(1, 1, 0)x(1, 0, 0, 12)

```
Dep. Variable:               National   No. Observations:                  443
Model:                 ARIMA(1, 0, 0)   Log Likelihood                2158.423
Date:                Tue, 05 Mar 2024   AIC                          -4310.847
Time:                        10:00:32   BIC                          -4298.566
Sample:                    02-01-1987   HQIC                         -4306.003
                         - 12-01-2023                                         
Covariance Type:                  opg                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const          0.0036      0.002      2.367      0.018       0.001       0.007
ar.L1          0.9392      0.012     80.942      0.000       0.916       0.962
sigma2      3.415e-06   1.03e-07     33.018      0.000    3.21e-06    3.62e-06
===================================================================================
Ljung-Box (L1) (Q):                   2.91   Jarque-Bera (JB):              1862.60
Prob(Q):                              0.09   Prob(JB):                         0.00
Heteroskedasticity (H):               6.80   Skew:                             0.96
Prob(H) (two-sided):                  0.00   Kurtosis:                        12.86
===================================================================================

==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:               National   No. Observations:                  443
Model:                 ARIMA(1, 1, 0)   Log Likelihood                2148.130
Date:                Tue, 05 Mar 2024   AIC                          -4292.260
Time:                        10:01:31   BIC                          -4284.078
Sample:                    02-01-1987   HQIC                         -4289.033
                         - 12-01-2023                                         
Covariance Type:                  opg                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ar.L1          0.0547      0.026      2.136      0.033       0.005       0.105
sigma2      3.512e-06   1.03e-07     34.197      0.000    3.31e-06    3.71e-06
===================================================================================
Ljung-Box (L1) (Q):                   0.00   Jarque-Bera (JB):              2665.10
Prob(Q):                              0.96   Prob(JB):                         0.00
Heteroskedasticity (H):               6.77   Skew:                             1.31
Prob(H) (two-sided):                  0.00   Kurtosis:                        14.74
===================================================================================

                                    SARIMAX Results                                     
========================================================================================
Dep. Variable:                         National   No. Observations:                  443
Model:             ARIMA(1, 1, 0)x(1, 0, 0, 12)   Log Likelihood                2159.325
Date:                          Tue, 05 Mar 2024   AIC                          -4312.651
Time:                                  10:01:58   BIC                          -4300.377
Sample:                              02-01-1987   HQIC                         -4307.810
                                   - 12-01-2023                                         
Covariance Type:                            opg                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ar.L1          0.0547      0.023      2.361      0.018       0.009       0.100
ar.S.L12       0.2169      0.027      8.184      0.000       0.165       0.269
sigma2      3.322e-06   9.67e-08     34.342      0.000    3.13e-06    3.51e-06
===================================================================================
Ljung-Box (L1) (Q):                   1.19   Jarque-Bera (JB):              2361.07
Prob(Q):                              0.28   Prob(JB):                         0.00
Heteroskedasticity (H):               5.86   Skew:                             0.96
Prob(H) (two-sided):                  0.00   Kurtosis:                        14.16
===================================================================================
```

EDIT 2: Plot is for monthly changes, not the original data.

Comment: In addition to Stephan's answer: The trend given by that `seasonal_decompose` function is a bit deceptive. It makes it appear as if the correction for seasonality had an influence. But that trend seems to be a smoothed function instead of the original data with the seasonal effect subtracted.

Comment: Your model (which may be for monthly changes to house prices rather than the data itself) seems to have been disrupted by the Global Financial Crisis in 2018 and by Covid-19 in  2020-21 and this is showing up in the residuals plot.  Meanwhile the seasonal pattern you have spotted is very small relative to the numbers you are using (-0.0005 to 0.0007 compared to -0.01 to almost 0.02) and may come from using slightly different seasonal adjustment algorithms to different forms of data without conveying useful information for your model.

Answer (score 7):

Please look at the $y$ axes of your decomposition plots, which are on vastly different scales. Your data is almost perfectly nonseasonal. [Compare this answer.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/354752/1352)

As to what I would do: I would use R's `auto.arima()` from the `forecast` or `fable` packages. The `pmdarima` package for Python reimplements this auto-ARIMA method. Using a well-tested automatic ARIMA fitter will usually yield better results than trying to "roll your own": [Selecting ARIMA orders by ACF/PACF vs. by information criteria](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/595150/1352)

Comment: doesn't the plots indicate increasing variability?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen: possibly, yes. It may be appropriate to look into that. However, I would definitely start by deploying simpler methods.

Comment: It is not so much increasing variability, but a non-stationary auto correlation relationship. In some times the behavior is very stable in other times it is very variable. Would a simple ARIMA achieve anything here?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus: the main question posted here is about the seasonality. I am arguing that the OP is misreading the decomposition plot and should absolutely worry less about this. It may well be that more sophisticated methods work better than a simple auto-ARIMA - but  my point is that we should first look at simpler auto-ARIMA, rather than hard-fit a seasonal model.

Comment: @StephanKolassa thanks for pointing that out. One sticking point is the Ljung-Box test, specially for lags >1. How should I navigate that? In terms of Log-Likelihood, AIC, BIC, ARIMA(1,1,0) performs better than AR(1). SARIMA is marginally better. I added the results to my question. And my question regarding GARCH still remains. Is it ok to fit GARCH with ARIMA errors?

Comment: You can't compare information criteria between models with different orders of differencing, which is why `auto.arima()` tests for unit roots to decide on this. Ljung-Box gives you $p=0.09$ for the (residuals of the) ARIMA(1,0,0), indicating no remaining autocorrelations, no? You can absolutely apply GARCH to the residuals of an auto-ARIMA fitted model. Whether it improves on forecast accuracy is another matter. I would usually prefer a holdout test over in-sample fitting statistics.

Comment: Another option is to use [Pareto smoothed importance sampling](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.02646) for model comparison if a probabilistic programming approach is taken.

Comment: @StephenKolassa could you elaborate on the following: If I plot these data like comparing with a filtered function, then I get a reasonable difference that sort of behaves periodically, but not very consistent. Peaks and valleys occur more or less with a year difference, but they shift in time and over the entire period they do not always occur in the same season. Does a simple ARIMA model capture this well (would it require a high order or can it work with low order)? And is an ARIMA model able to deal with the increasing variance after 2008.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaWJq.png

Comment: The image for the difference https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPFBC.png

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus: an ARIMA model might be able to *capture* this, but I would be concerned about whether it would then do much more than forecast out a random walk, because that might well be the best it fitted (see the AR1 coefficient in the ARIMA(1,0,0) model, which is 0.94, it really doesn't get much more random-walk-y than that). The question is whether GARCH will do much better. I don't really think a pure time series model is the way to go here; house prices are *hugely* dependent on macroeconomics (which are themselves hard to forecast meaningfully).

Comment: ... and ARIMA is not really built to account for changes in variance, that's what we use GARCH for... but that has "*conditional* heteroskedasticity" right in its name, conditional on *what*? And do we have a handle on the *conditions* so that we can leverage that for forecasting?