Question on decomposition plot (seasonality)
I cannot really understand the presence of seasonality by looking at the decomposition plots. Therefore, I attach two decomposition plots. Is there any seasonality in the series?
First one is CPI series (2003=100), monthly and seasonally unadjusted series

Second one is the inflation.


Your plots correspond to a multiplicative decomposition. The top plot gives the original observations, and the three ones below that give a decomposition
$$ y_i = t_is_ir_i $$
into a trend, a seasonal, and a "random" (i.e., residual) component.
To assess seasonality, look at the vertical axis for the seasonal component. In your first case, you see that the seasonal component varies between $0.995\leq s_i\leq 1.005$. That is, the seasonality gives a contribution of $\pm 0.5\%$. That is not a lot. In the second case, seasonality varies roughly in $0.75\leq s_i\leq 1.25$, so seasonality has an impact of $\pm 25\%$, which is quite a lot more. The second series thus seems to have a stronger seasonal signal.
Here is an earlier thread on this decomposition: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/354752/1352

thank you for your perfect explanation. I see! Well, how can I deal with this seasonality in R? and Which method should I use especially for inflation, CPI series and the like?

Per my comment on your earlier thread, how to "deal with seasonality" depends on what you want to do. If you want to forecast for instance, there are well established ways of determining whether a seasonal model is likely to improve on a non-seasonal one. If you want to feed your data into a model as a predictor, what makes most sense depends (and I know more about forecasting than about econometric modeling).
